# sageMath symbolic product failed for substutition and infinite

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, sage

The software was SageMath version 9.1, and the code mainly concerned [Sympy package's product function](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html#sympy.concrete.products.Product) as SageMath was cored with sympy.

The expression intended was product of

> (1-q)...(1-q^n)

with n range from 1 to infinity.

First, it was shown that [the product did recognize the infinity symbol](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/9047/symbolic-product-in-sage/)

```
product(1/x^2, x, 1, oo)
```

returned the correct result of 0.

**Error 1**
However, the code

```
product(1-a^x, x, 1, oo)
```

returned error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d7561515fdb5> in <module>()
----> 1 product(Integer(1)-a**x, x, Integer(1), oo)

/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/misc/functional.py in symbolic_prod(expression, *args, **kwds)
    629     from .misc_c import prod as c_prod
    630     if hasattr(expression, 'prod'):
--> 631         return expression.prod(*args, **kwds)
    632     elif len(args) <= 1:
    633         return c_prod(expression, *args)

/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/symbolic/expression.pyx in sage.symbolic.expression.Expression.prod (build/cythonized/sage/symbolic/expression.cpp:63909)()
  12375         """
  12376         from sage.calculus.calculus import symbolic_product
> 12377         return symbolic_product(self, *args, **kwds)
  12378 
  12379     def integral(self, *args, **kwds):

/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/calculus/calculus.py in symbolic_product(expression, v, a, b, algorithm, hold)
    867 
    868     if algorithm == 'maxima':
--> 869         return maxima.sr_prod(expression,v,a,b)
    870 
    871     elif algorithm == 'mathematica':

/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/maxima_lib.py in sr_prod(self, *args)
    902         """
    903         try:
--> 904             return max_to_sr(maxima_eval([[max_ratsimp],[[max_simplify_prod],([max_prod],[sr_to_max(SR(a)) for a in args])]]));
    905         except RuntimeError as error:
    906             s = str(error)

/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/maxima_lib.py in max_to_sr(expr)
   1683             op=max_op_dict[op_max]
   1684         max_args=cdr(expr)
-> 1685         args=[max_to_sr(a) for a in max_args]
   1686         return op(*args)
   1687     elif expr.symbolp():

/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/maxima_lib.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1683             op=max_op_dict[op_max]
   1684         max_args=cdr(expr)
-> 1685         args=[max_to_sr(a) for a in max_args]
   1686         return op(*args)
   1687     elif expr.symbolp():

/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/interfaces/maxima_lib.py in max_to_sr(expr)
   1684         max_args=cdr(expr)
   1685         args=[max_to_sr(a) for a in max_args]
-> 1686         return op(*args)
   1687     elif expr.symbolp():
   1688         if not(expr in max_sym_dict):

/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/rings/integer.pyx in sage.rings.integer.Integer.__pow__ (build/cythonized/sage/rings/integer.c:14994)()
   2222             return (<Integer>left)._pow_(right)
   2223         elif isinstance(left, Element):
-> 2224             return coercion_model.bin_op(left, right, operator.pow)
   2225         # left is a non-Element: do the powering with a Python int
   2226         return left ** int(right)

/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/coerce.pyx in sage.structure.coerce.CoercionModel.bin_op (build/cythonized/sage/structure/coerce.c:10143)()
   1209             self._record_exception()
   1210         else:
-> 1211             return PyObject_CallObject(op, xy)
   1212 
   1213         if op is mul:

/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/structure/element.pyx in sage.structure.element.Element.__pow__ (build/cythonized/sage/structure/element.c:14059)()
   2034         cdef int cl = classify_elements(left, right)
   2035         if HAVE_SAME_PARENT(cl):
-> 2036             return (<Element>left)._pow_(right)
   2037         if BOTH_ARE_ELEMENT(cl):
   2038             return coercion_model.bin_op(left, right, pow)

/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/symbolic/expression.pyx in sage.symbolic.expression.Expression._pow_ (build/cythonized/sage/symbolic/expression.cpp:25373)()
   4092                            relational_operator(self._gobj))
   4093         else:
-> 4094             x = g_pow(self._gobj, nexp._gobj)
   4095         return new_Expression_from_GEx(self._parent, x)
   4096 

ValueError: power::eval(): pow(1, Infinity) is not defined.
```

**Error 2**
An indefinite expression was also defined

```
expres1=product(1-a^x, x, 1, N)
```

which returned

```
-(-1)^N*product(a^x - 1, x, 1, N)
```

However, with the substitution

```
h=expres1.substitute({N:10})
```

which returned

```
-product(a^x - 1, x, 1, 10)
```

the symbolic expression h could not be expanded

```
(h).series(a,10).expand()
```

returned error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e9b5fcf66965> in <module>()
      1 #help(prod)
      2 #(1/eta_1).series(q,10).expand()
----> 3 (h).series(a,Integer(10)).expand()

/opt/sagemath-9.1/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sage/symbolic/expression.pyx in sage.symbolic.expression.Expression.series (build/cythonized/sage/symbolic/expression.cpp:27193)()
   4484         sig_on()
   4485         try:
-> 4486             x = self._gobj.expand(0).series(symbol0._gobj, cprec, options)
   4487             nex = SymbolicSeries.__new__(SymbolicSeries)
   4488             nex._parent = self._parent

ValueError: power::eval(): division by zero
```

**Question**

Could you tell me what went wrong with the above codes? Why sageMath did not recognize the infinite product? Why the substitution did not work, and that the program could not evaluate the function?